# Запятая между определениями

Tags: стилистика, пунктуация

Замечательная симпатичная девушка. 
Можно ли не ставить запятую, чтобы разделить характер и внешность? Изменится ли что-нибудь, если переставить определения местами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь художественное определение (определение-эпитет). С помощью таких определений подчёркивается каждая отдельная деталь описания (хотя они и характеризуют предмет с разных сторон). Ср.: ***Сытые, белые, важные птицы шли по плотине (А. Толстой).*** Поэтому запятая нужна. Перестановка определений смысл не изменит.